# Saving a multidimensional array into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I am working on a online time tracking web page. But i am stuck at the part on transferring the data into the database.

```html
<?php
 /* This loop will iterate through all days.  */
 foreach($_POST["startTime"] as $day=>$startTimes){
   /* This loop will give start & end times for a particular day, i.e. $day */
       
   foreach($startTimes as $timeIndex=>$startTime){
   $endTime = $_POST["endTime"][$day][$timeIndex];

     if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      } else {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO timetableschedule (name, day, startTime, endTime) ". 
         "VALUES ('$name', '$day', '$startTime', '![enter image description here][1]$endTime')";
      
        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "1 record added";
        mysqli_close($con);
      }
     }        
    }       

      ?>
```

**The form looks like this,**

[image]

```html
<table id="dataTable" class="form-control">
                       <label for="Monday">Monday</label>
         <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <p>
                          <td>
                              <label>Start Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[1][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <label>End Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[1][]">
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <table id="dataTable1" class="form-control">
                       <label for="Monday">Tuesday</label>
        <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable1')" /> 
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <p>
                          <td>
                              <label>Start Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[2][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <label>End Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[2][]">
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <table id="dataTable2" class="form-control">
                       <label for="Monday">Wednesday</label>
        <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable2')" /> 
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <p>
                          <td>
                              <label>Start Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[3][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <label>End Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[3][]">
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <table id="dataTable3" class="form-control">
                       <label for="Monday">Thursday</label>
        <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable3')" /> 
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <p>
                          <td>
                              <label>Start Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[4][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <label>End Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[4][]">
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <table id="dataTable4" class="form-control">
                       <label for="Monday">Friday</label>
        <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable4')" /> 
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <p>
                          <td>
                              <label>Start Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[5][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <label>End Time</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[5][]">
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
      </table>
```

**The database should look like this,**

[image]

But the only the first row of data managed to enter the database. I am not sure where when wrong with my php codes.

Comment: Sorry but "But the only the first row of data managed to enter the database." is not clear. Explain more. When I check your form and the datas saved into db, I don't understand what's wrong (what's the datas ino db should be).

Comment: for example, Monday 1230hrs - 1400hrs is one row of data, if there is another Tuesday 1300hrs - 1500hrs it did not appear in the database.

Comment: Still not clear for me sorry... I let somebody else trying to help you !

Comment: i think i am missing some loop coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html to this

```
                 <td>
                          <label>Start Time</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time[0]['start']">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <label>End Time</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time[0]['end']">
                      </td>
```

Rest indices will be

```
time[1]['start']
time[1]['end']
```

and so on

Then your php code will be easier to read

```
foreach($_POST['time'] as $day => $time) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO timetableschedule (name, day, startTime, endTime) ". 
                       "VALUES ('$name', '$day', '" . $time['start'] . "', '" . $time['end'] . "')";
}
```

Comment: Undefined index: start, Undefined index: end

Comment: In HTML, change `['start']` into `[start]`.

Comment: @Hkan only the last array set gets to enter into the database

Comment: Make sure that your inputs are not all `time[0][start]`, and that the number is incremented. Like, first *start time* input is `time[0][start]`, second *start time* input is `time[1][start]`, third is `time[2][start]` etc.